# Cast object to a generic type

Tags: c#, generics, serialization

I haven't slept in a while so this is probably easier than I think it is.

I have a generic class that's more or less this:

```
public class Reference<T> where T : APIResource //<- APIResource is abstract btw
{
    private T _value = null;
    public T value
    { 
        get { return _value; }
    }
}
```

Elsewhere, in a custom serialize method, someone is passing in an `object` that is actually an instance of `Reference<(something)>`. I simply want to skip to the "value" property that every `Reference<>` object has, so I want to go:

```
string serialize(object o)
{
    return base.serialize( ((Reference<>) o).value );
}
```

Of course, life isn't that simple because as the compiler puts it:

`using the generic type "Reference<T>" requires 1 type arguments`

How can I do what I want to do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a covariant generic interface with the property:

```
interface IReference<out T> where T : ApiResource {
    T Value { get; }
}
```

You can then cast `IReference<Anything>` to `IReference<object>` or `IReference<ApiResource>`.

Comment: I knew absolutely nothing about covariant generic interfaces so I'm really glad I turned to SO. I had to modify the generic class accordingly: `public class Reference<T> : IReference<T> where T : APIResource { ... }`. This allows me to retrieve the Value property with `((IReference<APIResource>) o).Value`

Answer (score 3):

SLaks answer is perfect. I just want to extend it a little bit:

There are sometimes situations, where you can't substitute class with interface. **Only** in that cases you may want to use `dynamic` feature, so that you can call `value` property:

```
string serialize(object o)
{
    if(typeof(Reference<>) == o.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition())
        return base.serialize( ((dynamic)o).value );

    //in your case you will throw InvalidCastException
    throw new ArgumentException("not a Reference<>", "o"); 
}
```

This is just another options and I suggest to use it very carefully.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative. Clearly this is a last resort, but very important to have here in case someone can't modify the generic class in question.

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget to check whether its generic type or not ---> o.GetType().IsGenericType, before

using o.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() else it throws exception..