# Populating a Collection of Wrapped<A> with Wrapped<B> classes where B implements A

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance

So I have the following simple wrapper class:

```
interface IReference<out T> where T : myAbstractBase {
    T Value { get; }
}
public class Reference<T> : IReference<T> where T : myAbstractBase
{
    private T _value = null;
    public T Value {  get { return _value; } }
}
```

Throughout my application, I want to have collections of these `IReference<someClass>` objects (where `someClass` implements `myAbstractBase`)

```
private List<Reference<shapes>> shapeList = new Collection<Reference<shapes>>();
```

But I want to be able to add all kinds of different shapes to this collection. (Especially since shape is also abstract). Of course, this yields an error:

```
shapeList.Add( new Reference<circle>(){ radius = 2; } );
```

`The value "Reference[circle]" is not of type "Reference[shape]" and cannot be used in this generic collection.`

Is there any way I can design my `Reference<T>` class such that so long as `A` is of type `B`, `Reference<A>` will be considered of type `Reference<B>`?

Seems to me like people would run into the same sort of problem trying to use lists of `Nullable`, etc.

I've tried implementing implicit operators for converting between Reference and T, but I haven't thought of any practical use for them...

```
public class Reference<T> ... {
    ...

    public static implicit operator Reference<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Reference<T> { _value = value, };
    }
    public static implicit operator T(Reference<T> value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }
}
```

To anyone curious about my intentions, this is all part of an (ill-fated) attempt to implement lazy loading for a set of classes without having to without having to add anything more to those classes.

Comment: You would have to use <in T>, and that wouldn't work for your interface.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance You know, I'm not sure why that interface is that way. It came from this question earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795750/cast-object-to-a-generic-type, but the interface seems to do it's job even with T defined as invariant.

Comment: Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29) says the the `IList<T>` type constructor is invariant so no two lists are a subtype of the other. Does this mean this is a lost cause with lists?

Comment: Does using a list of `IReferences` instead of `References` work for you: `List<IReference<Shape>> shapeList = new List<IReference<Shape>>();`

Comment: @steaks, That doesn't work because unlike my `Reference<T>` implicit converters, I can't define implicit converters for the Interface class, so I wouldn't be able to go `List<IReference<circle>> circleList.Add( new circle() )` like I can now (because it automatically converts circle to `Reference<Circle>`)

Comment: So `shapeList.Add( new Reference<circle>(){ radius = 2; } )` isn't quite what you're trying to do?

Comment: I primarily use it to add objects `X` to collections `List<Reference<X>>`, but every now and then I have an abstract class `A` which is implemented by `B`, `C`, and `D`, and someone has a `List<Reference<A>>` which needs to hold a bunch of `B`, `C` and `D` instances (which of course get automatically converted to `Reference<B>`, `Reference<C>`, and `Reference<D>` instances), and it's in converting those wrapped instances to `Reference<A>` that's failing;

Comment: there must be some way to make the type declaration of Reference<T> covariant so that `Reference<circle>` is a `Reference<shape>`...

Comment: Classes and structs do not support covariance in C#, only interfaces.  You can only cast to get from a `Reference<Circle>` to a `Reference<Shape>`.  I explain in my updated answer why you can't only use implicit casting to go from a `Reference<Circle>` to a `Reference<Shape>`.  The other way to get around your problem would be to use `IReference<Shape>`.  Interfaces are useful for you because they can be covariant, but they don't support implicit casting.  So interfaces also don't get you exactly to what you want.  I think I give you a solution in my updated answer that gets you what you want.

Comment: Interfaces don't support user defined implicit casts*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rephrased the question and got an answer in another thread: [How to cast a Generic<T> to a Generic<R> where T is a subclass of R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261063/how-to-cast-a-generict-to-a-genericr-where-t-is-a-subclass-of-r)

The trick was to create a covariant interface `IReference<out T>` and always use the interface wherever the type is used. So declaring `List<IReference<myAbstractBase>>` rather than `List<Reference<myAbstractBase>>`. Details as to why this works at [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you can't chain user defined implicit casts.  At first glance it seems like you should be able go from `Reference<Circle>` -> `Reference<Shape>` via `Reference<Circle>` -> `Circle` -> `Shape` -> `Reference<Shape>`.  However, you'd be using two user defined implicit casts.  First you'd go from `Reference<Circle>` -> `Circle` via `operator T(Reference<T> value)`.  Then you'd go from 
`Shape` -> `Reference<Shape>` via `operator Reference<T>(T value)`.  You can get around this by creating an overload of the Add method by extending `List`.  This will free you to use one of the user defined cast operators explicitly in `Reference.Add`.  Now, you won't have to chain user defined implicit cast operators.

See the spec on user defined implicit casts: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691302(v=vs.71).aspx

```
//You can get around your inability to chain user defined implicit casts
//by creating a ReferenceList<T> that extends List<IReference<T>>
//and overloads the List.Add method
public class ReferenceList<T> : List<IReference<T>> where T : MyAbstractBase
{
    //With this overload you can accept a T.  Then explicity cast to Reference<T>
    //by using operator Reference<T>(T value)
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        base.Add((Reference<T>)item);
    }
}
List<Reference<Shape>> shapeList = new List<Reference<Shape>>();
ReferenceList<Shape> shapeList2 = new ReferenceList<Shape>();
List<IReference<Shape>> shapeList3 = new List<IReference<Shape>>();

//Interesting cases that should work with the OP

//Works for obvious reasons
shapeList.Add(new Reference<Shape>());
//Works because you're using one user defined implicit cast 
//where the cast is operator Reference<T>(T value).
//Shape -> Reference<Shape>
shapeList.Add(new Shape());
//Works because you're using one non user defined implicit cast and one user defined 
//implicit cast where the user defined implicit cast is operator Reference<T>(T value)
//Circle -> Shape -> Wrapper<Shape>
shapeList.Add(new Circle());
//Does not work because you need to chain two user defined implicit casts
//where the implicit casts are operator T(Reference<T> value) and operator Reference<T>(T value)
//Reference<Circle> -> Circle -> Shape -> Reference<Shape>
//Theoretically this could work, but the C# specs state that chaining user defined
//implicit casts is not allowed in C# (See link below)
shapeList.Add(new Reference<Circle>());
//This case works for similiar reasons that shapeList.Add(new Circle()).  It uses
//only one user defined implicit cast because you're calling operator T(Reference<T> value)
//explicitely  
shapeList.Add(new (Circle)Reference<Circle>());

//Interesting cases for ReferenceList

//Works because this calls List.Add which accepts a Reference<T>
shapeList2.Add(new Reference<Shape>());
//Works because this calls ReferenceList.Add wich accepts a T
shapeList2.Add(new Circle());
//Works because this calls ReferenceList.Add wich accepts a T.
//and Reference<Circle> can be implicitly cast to a Circle via
//operator T(Reference<T> value).
//Reference<Circle> -> Circle -> Shape -> Reference<Shape> where
//the last cast is done explicitely in the ReferenceList.Add method
//via operator Reference<T>(T value)
shapeList2.Add(new Reference<Circle>());

//Interesting cases for List<IReference<Shape>>


//Works for obvious reasons
shapeList3.Add(new Reference<Shape>());
//Works because IReference is covariant.  In C# interfaces can be
//covariant.  Classes cannot be covariant.
shapeList3.Add(new Reference<Circle>());
//Does not work because C# does not support user defined implicit
//casts to interface.  In other words, you implicitly cast Shape -> Reference<Shape>
shapeList3.Add(new Shape());
//Doesn't work for similiar reasons to why shapeList3.Add(new Shape()) doesn't work
shapeList3.Add(new Circle());
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's a shot in the dark that should at least make your implicit operator compile. I don't have anything setup that I can test it with right off hand. Still, it should work. Add this to the Reference class.

```
public static implicit operator Reference<myAbstractBase>(Reference<T> i)
{
    return i;
}
```

Note there's a lack of type checking going on here, so if T *isn't* derived from myAbstractBase you could be hosed.

Comment: I tried to define implicit converters from `Reference<T>` to `Reference<myAbstractBase>`, `Reference<T> to Reference<shape>`, `Reference<T> to Reference<circle>`, but when trying to put a `Reference<circle>` into a `List<Reference<shape>>` it still complains about not being able to convert `Reference<circle>` to `Reference<shape>` :/

Comment: What happens when you make the converters explicit and/or add them to a list with an explicit conversion?

Answer (score 0):

I've started down the path of defining a custom collection that is exactly a `List<Reference<T>>` inside, but it seems to be doing the trick:

```
public class ReferenceCollection<T> : ICollection<T> where T : myAbstractBase 
{
    private List<Reference<T>> collection = new List<Reference<T>>();

    public IEnumerable<T> toIEnumerable()
    {
        return (IEnumerable<T>) collection.Select(r => r.Value);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return toIEnumerable().GetEnumerator(); ;
    }

    #region ICollection<T> Members
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        collection.Add(item);
    }
    ...
}
```

Now I can make the folling call (which I couldn't do before):

```
ReferenceCollection<shape> test = new ReferenceCollection<shape>();
test.Add(new circle());
```

Why is it working this way but not the other? Am I really doing anything all that different? Perhaps the conversion is actually now happening in the opposite order (circle gets cast to shape, and then shape gets implicitly converted to `Resource<shape>` as it's added to the internal collection.)

I can't see any downfalls to this method yet. I could even define implicit converters to turn a `ReferenceCollection<T>` directly into a `List<T>` or `List<Reference<T>>` without so much as iterating over it. Still, I wonder if there's a way to define the original class such that the cast is similarly happening before the implicit conversion to avoid the un-castable wrapped type.

Comment: You posted that `shapeList.Add( new Reference<circle>(){ radius = 2; } )` didn't work in your original problem.  Are you sure that `shapeList.Add( new circle(){ radius = 2; } )` didn't work?

Comment: @steaks Yes it fails because `shapeList` is a `List<IReference<Shape>>()`, not a `List<Shape>()`. It was first converting the added circle instanec to an `IReference<Circle>` and then understandably failing to convert that into an `IReference<Shape>`.

Comment: This ended up being no good - I can no longer deserialize Reference<circle> objects into the class because the enumerator now exposes it as a collection of shape objects. circle can be cast to shape and shape can be cast to Reference<shape> but Reference<circle> cannot be cast to Reference<shape> so the deserializer crashes. Same problem, just reversed now.