# How to cast a Generic<T> to a Generic<R> where T is a subclass of R?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Is there a way to define an explicit converter or anything similar such that the compiler can automatically populate a `Generic<T>` from a `Generic<R>` `where T : R` ?

The error message I get is:

> The value "Reference`1[Dog]" is not of type "Reference`1[Pet]" and cannot be used in this generic collection.

My reference class looks like this:

```
public interface IReference<T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public class Reference<T> : IReference<T>
{
    #region Properties
    public string ref_type { get; set; }
    public string ref_id { get; set; }
    public Uri href { get; set; }

    private bool resolved = false;
    private T _value = default(T);

    public T Value
    { 
        get
        {
            if( !resolved && href != null ) resolve();
            else if( href == null ) return null;
            return _value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public Reference() { }
    public Reference(string ref_id) 
    {
        this.ref_id = ref_id;
    }
    #endregion

    #region members
    private void resolve()
    {
        if( href != null )
        {
            _value = APIRequestMethods.GetUri<T>(href);
            resolved = true;
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("Cannot resolve the reference because the href property has not been set.");
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: You're looking for covariance.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx

Comment: co/contra variance may be an answer depending on code/need  `Generic<in T>` or `Generic<out T>`...

Comment: No, unless `Generic` is an interface and the type parameter is covariant.

Comment: On a side note, do you know about Lazy<T>?

Comment: @Slugart I didn't know about it! I'll consider using it in my implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will only work if your generic type is an interface, and you make your generic type covariant, ie: `IGeneric<out T>`.

Note that this will only work for interfaces or delegates.  For details, see [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).

Comment: I've included my definition. It's supposed to be a method for lazy loading arbitrarily typed objects (over a rest API)

Comment: @Alain If you used `IReference<out T>`, and *always use the interface*, it could work.

Comment: If I do `public List<IReference<Pet>> pets = new List<Reference<Pet>>();` I get `Cannot implicitly convert type 'List<Reference<Pet>>' to 'List<IReference<Pet>>'`. When I do `public List<IReference<Pet>> pets = new List<IReference<Pet>>();`, I get `Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface` (of course).

Comment: @Alain You can do `List<IReference<Pet>> pets = new List<IReference<Pet>>();` - that will work.  Then add in: `pets.Add(new Reference<Dog>(new Dog()));`

Comment: This is brutally complicated because JSON deserializers aren't smart enough to not try and create new instances of this interface when deserializing a list of references, forcing me to create convoluted code that does something like `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Reference<>).MakeGenericType(t));`, but I digress. This is certainly the right direction to take and I think I can see the light at the end of the tunnel. Thanks for advising this approach.